# BOOLEAN error in following script?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Need help finding error in following BOOLEAN script. What's wrong?

Filter Logic: **(1 AND 2 AND 3) AND 4**

1. **Google Agreement Category** equals **"Procurement"**
2. **Agreement: Owner Name** does not contain **"David"**
3. **Agreement: Owner Name** does not contain **"Goliath"**
4. **Status Category** equals **"In effect,Amended"**

Script being used to filter through a list of legal contracts.

"Agreement category": a type of agreement (or contract)

"Owner Name": The name of whoever owns/started said contract.

"Status Category": status of said contract (in effect, deactivated, created, etc.)

What's wrong?

Comment: S/O is a site for programming questions (questions that involve code). Homework questions are not well accepted here.

Comment: @AaronGillion [Homework questions are allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as long as they follow all other guidelines for being on-topic.  [Code is not required](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291399/is-there-really-a-universal-code-requirement/291400#291400) for questions to be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Then so what is your quistion and where you got a error.

*AND operator always used in boolean then why you are using in base 10 (or with string)*